# Scraping Links Off Google Search Results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a program that will output links for the search results of google queries. Here is my program:

```
# import necessary libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"}

# assign URL
url_to_scrape = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats"
  
# create document
html_document = requests.get(url_to_scrape, headers=headers).text
  
# create soap object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'html.parser')
  
# find all the anchor tags with "href" 
# attribute starting with "https://"
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    # display the actual urls
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I have tried a couple different things but I keep getting this output:

```
maps.google.com/maps?q=cats&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv85nI8qr-AhXCjYkEHVQaAd0Q_AUICSgE

www.google.com/search?ei=TRM6ZK-ZE8KbptQP1LSE6A0&q=cats&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv85nI8qr-AhXCjYkEHVQaAd0Q7Al6BAgMEAw

preferences?hl=en&fg=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv85nI8qr-AhXCjYkEHVQaAd0Q5fUCCPEB

policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en&fg=1

policies.google.com/terms?hl=en&fg=1
```

(I had to remove pieces of the links to not set off the spam fiter)

I'm not sure why this program doesn't just print out the first links that google returns from the search. I am a beginner at web scraping so any pointers are appreciated.